# OSError: libtest.so: undefined symbol: g_tree_new

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries

when i try to open (dlopen() in python) I get an error as above.

> libtest.so has some functions which use g_tree_new
>
> g_tree_new is defined in libglib-2.0.so.0

I tried setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to where `libglib-2.0.so.0` is,
but that does not help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you link in libglib when building libtest? That is, you need to have -lglib-2.0 in your link command line.

Comment: i checked the link option and I have -Wl,-L/local/home/vij/libglib -lglib-2.0